# Keras. Is it possible to use the batch output of a layer as input of the next layer?

Tags: python, keras

I am trying to train a Keras implementation of VGGish. 
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/audioset
VGGish purpose is to classify audio data.

VGGish takes as input a batch of mel spectrograms (basically, these are pictures), each spectrogram being the representation of 1 second and returns a batch of embeddings of shape `(batch size, 128)`. So to process a 10 seconds long audio file, you first convert it as a batch of 10 mel spectogram, and you get an output of shape `(10, 128)`.

Now, I would like to add a classifier on top of VGGish, that means adding layers. As the shape `(10, 128)` is a time series I would like to convolve on the first dimension or use a LSTM, whatever is suited.

The problem is that the shape of the embbedding is determined by `(batch size, units=128)`.

In short, you input a batch of `n` seconds. What I would like to do, is being able to input a batch of `n` files of 10 seconds, and work at the file level, not the second level.

It gives me headache, really.

The beginning of the VGGish is like this :

```
input_shape = (vggish_params.NUM_FRAMES,vggish_params.NUM_BANDS)

img_input = Input( shape=input_shape)
reshaped = Reshape((vggish_params.NUM_FRAMES,vggish_params.NUM_BANDS,1))(img_input)
# Block 1
x = Conv2D(64, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same', name='conv1')(reshaped)
x = MaxPooling2D((2, 2), strides=(2, 2), name='pool1')(x)
```

The Reshape layer serves to be able to Conv 2D. The output layer for embedding looks like this :

```
x = Dense(128, activation='relu', name='fc2')(x)
```

What I would like to do overall is to add one dimension. What I mean by this is inputting batches of `n` seconds audio clips, instead of batches of n 1-second clips.

I really have no clue on how to do that, and I don't know if it's even possible. I come here for help, because I'm really really puzzled.

Any idea ?
Cheers.

Comment: I think the concept your are missing is "timesteps", which is used to implement recurrent networks.

Comment: To be precise I'm not missing this concept in the sense that I'm not aware of it. What I miss though it the way to take it into account given the achitecture I'm provided with VGGish.

I mean I can build another network with input (seconds, 128) and convolve or RNN on it. I did it and it works. But what I would like it to have one network instead of 2. So the idea is to combine VGGish base network with the top classifier network. My problem is the discrepancy in the shapes of the layes